# Error in installing shapes module in Python

Tags: python, pip, turtle-graphics, shapes, pysal

Hey Guys I written some code to make a simple hut using turtle and shapes in python but when i am importing the shapes then it is showing me error this is the error [image: this is the error]

here is my code

```
import turtle
from shapes import *

# naming the turtle
pen = turtle.Turtle()

# setting up turtle
pen.speed(100)
pen.color(0,0,0)
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.color(66,202,244)

#start drawing
drawWindow(pen,-95,15,"square")
drawHouse(pen)
drawDoor(pen,-25,-20)
drawBush(pen,120,35)
drawWindow(pen,-10,100,"circle")
drawFence(pen)
drawPath(pen)
drawWindow(pen,-95,100,"square")
drawGrass(pen)
drawCloud(pen,75,160)
drawWindow(pen,75,15,"square")
drawSun(pen,-200,160,70)
drawWindow(pen,180,150,"square")
```

then i read a solution for this to install "pysal" but when I am installing pysal(pip install pysal) from cmd then it is also showing this error while installing pysal
[image: this error i am getting in cmd while installing pysal]

please resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The error says no module is named shapes to solve that you need to `pip install shapes`

Comment: If you need any clarifications please comment bellow this comment

Answer (score 0):

There is the code in [`shapes/__init__.py`](https://github.com/dominicwhite/shapes/blob/5e71ffa12cbf97bec977e4d4f859b0ef069efcd3/shapes/__init__.py#L1):

```
from Shape import Shape
```

The code works under Python 2 and doesn't work under Python 3. For Python 3 it must be either

```
from shapes.Shape import Shape
```

or

```
from .Shape import Shape
```

The same problem with other relative imports. The bottom line: the package `shapes` is Python2-only. Please [report the problem](https://github.com/dominicwhite/shapes/issues) or even better send a pull-request to fix it.